# Cannot view app logs on device

Tags: android, logcat

I have enabled the logging in my manifest file using

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

I connected the device via usb and could see the app logs in the Logcat view. But the same logs are not getting registered in the device when viewed from third party apps like alogcat or logviewer.

Is there anything else that i need to enable to view the logs on these applications?

Comment: Is it possible that the third party viewer is filtering by log entry severity? For instance, it may only be showing entries at the Error level and above but you could be logging at the Debug or Info level.

Comment: I tried using filter for all the levels. But its only showing the system level logs but not the app logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices keep a very small amount of log traces on the device. I often receive log files consisting of 20-25 lines. On such devices your traces will be overwritten very fast and they are not helpful. You cannot change this. This is device configuration.

If you want to see complete log, you need to use logging libraries available for Java and Android. They will store all your logs. If you need to analyse exceptions, you might ask users to report issues via Google Play too. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder why the logcat in the eclipse shows the app logs but the third party apps doesnot show them at all.